# Regex for one letter and 6 numbers in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Entering the user number in the text box with the `webmethod GetSearchUser` returns the name of user.

I have this regular expression to test if an input starts with the letter "a" or "A" and is followed by 6 numbers. On the online validator seems to work.

The problem is that when the user number is replaced with the the name of user this string is not validated. And it is correct.

But how do I then check that user number is entered correctly and validate the string when the user number is replaced with the the name of user?

My code below.

```
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                    ServiceMethod="GetSearchUser"
                    ServicePath="prefix.aspx"
                    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                    CompletionInterval="10"
                    EnableCaching="false"
                    CompletionSetCount="10"
                    TargetControlID="txuser"
                    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
                    runat="server"
                    FirstRowSelected="false">
                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txuser" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" CssClass="pure-u-23-24"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator29" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txuser"
                    SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Required" Text=""
                    Display="None" ValidationGroup="ValidationSummaryUser"
                    CssClass="validation-summary-errors-one"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txuser"
                    SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Required : AXXXXXX" Text=""
                    Display="None" ValidationExpression="/^(a|A)([0-9]{6})$/" ValidationGroup="ValidationSummaryUser"
                    CssClass="validation-summary-errors-one"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


[ScriptMethod()]
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetSearchUser(string prefixText)
{
    DataTable Result = new DataTable();
    string str = @String.Format("SELECT Name FROM `users` ");
    str += String.Format(" WHERE user_number LIKE '" + prefixText + "%' ");
    str += String.Format(" ORDER BY Name ASC;");

    using (OdbcConnection con =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        da = new OdbcDataAdapter(str, con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<string> Output = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            Output.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        return Output;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It must be `ValidationExpression="^[aA][0-9]{6}$"`, not `ValidationExpression="/^(a|A)([0-9]{6})$/"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Try out `^[aA][0-9]{6}$` without success, thanks for help.

Comment: What are your specifications for a user name? You need to incorporate that into your RegEx.

Comment: If the number is being replaced by username, then you need a different regex. Could you give an example?

Comment: @RoadRunner Please see **EDIT** in this quetion.

Comment: @RoadRunner Entering the user number in the text box in format A123456 with the webmethod GetSearchUser returns the name of user, e.g. UNCLE VINCE. The problem is that when the user number A123456 is replaced with the the name of user UNCLE VINCE this string is not validated, because this regular expression to test if an input starts with the letter "a" or "A" and is followed by 6 numbers. In this case when the username was found by its number the string must be validated. You see my **EDIT** ?

Comment: @UncleVince Oh I see. When you submit the text in the textbox, the `GetSearchUserMethod` is called, which converts your `A123456` to `UNCLE VINCE`, then the regex says its invalid?

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I'm afraid that the `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` is unable to complete two validations at the same time.

What you need might be a custom validator which could do both validation for the text box.

Solution: using `<asp:CustomValidator>`

You could do validation from both server side and client side (I did it from client side).

It can be used as a combination of `RequiredValidator`, `RegularExpressionValidator` and extra custom style validation.

More details, you could refer to below code:

**.aspx :**

```
     <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
            OnClientItemSelected="itemSelected"
            ServiceMethod="GetSearchUser"
            ServicePath="AutoCompleteExtenderValidation.aspx"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1"
            CompletionInterval="10"
            EnableCaching="false"
            CompletionSetCount="10"
            TargetControlID="txuser"
            ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
            runat="server"
            FirstRowSelected="false">
        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txuser" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" CssClass="pure-u-23-24"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_txuser" runat="server" />


        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorFortxuser" runat="server" 
            ClientValidationFunction="custom_validation" ControlToValidate="txuser" 
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required AXXXX or Valid UserName" 
            ValidationGroup="ValidationSummaryUser" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationSummaryUser" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>            
    </div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function itemSelected(sender, ev) {
            //When selected value from the return list, it will be kept in the hidden field for the following validation
            var selectedValue = ev._value;
            $('#<%= hf_txuser.ClientID%>').val(selectedValue);

        }
        function custom_validation(source, arguments) {

            if (arguments.Value == "") {

                arguments.IsValid = false;

            } else {
                //Valid if one of checks pass: fulfill the regex or equals to hidden field value. No worries about the empty content
                arguments.IsValid = (regexValidate(arguments) || arguments.Value  == $('#<%= hf_txuser.ClientID%>').val());
            }

            if (!arguments.IsValid) {
                $('#<%= Label1.ClientID%>').text("");
            }

        }

        function regexValidate(input) {
            var patt = /^(a|A)([0-9]{6})$/;
            return patt.test(input);
        }
    </script>
```

**.cs code:**

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = txuser.Text + " Submit successfully!";
}
```

You should include `Jquery` in the `<head>` since I have used `Jquery` in the code for assigning value to the hidden field.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The version could be any one as long as it works for value assignment.

Hope this can help you.